# ubuntu 20.04 screen driver failed after kernel update

Tags: server, kernel, xorg

I have an Ubuntu VPS that I installed lxdm as a default display manager and the xfce as the desktop environment, also I enabled auto login. I was using Anydesk for remote control.

Everything was working until recently I updated and rebooted the system.

After report I got stuck in the log in prompt, it shows for 1 second the then it disappear then shows over and over

I do not know where to start to fix this

I have SSH and VNC access

I appreciate any suggestion

This is the error log:

```
** Message: 19:20:09.149: find greeter (nil)
** Message: 19:20:09.174: find idle (nil)
** Message: 19:20:09.201: 1652199609: add xserver watch
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux vmi520843.contaboserver.net 5.4.0-109-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic root=UUID=61d59aba-cb81-4057-99c0-81b122d84211 ro net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 nomodeset
Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue May 10 19:20:09 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org
for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: *"lxdm as a default display manager and the xfce as the desktop environment"* - Can you describe how exactly you set this up? I imagine you needed to do quite a bit to get these working together at the same time.  Or was this the first time you restarted after installing these packages? How did you update the kernel? What kernel version are you trying to run? Did you try to boot the older kernel?

Comment: Thanks @Nmath, I appreciate it if u can take a look, I did that long time ago I do not remember, everything was fine until the recent update, I am using webmin as an admin panel, If u have some time I can give u VNC and SSH access